# how do I group by timestamp in an order of values in a column?

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, group-by, databricks

Hi I have a table like this below

| item_name | item_value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hpc_max | 0.25 | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.34 | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| off_median | 0.30 | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| hpc_max | 0.54 | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.32 | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
| off_median | 0.67 | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.54 | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| off_median | 0.32 | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
| hpc_max | 0.67 | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |

I'm grouping item_values by timestamp using this command below

```
grouped_df = (
    df.groupBy("timestamp")
    .agg(sort_array(collect_list("item_values")).alias("item_values"))
)

result = [row["item_values"] for row in grouped_df.sort("timestamp").collect()]
```

and the return output is something like this

```
[[10.046214032028468,
  10.112576620155044,
  23.68193075],
 [10.046214032028468,
  10.112576620155044,
  23.660212571428573]]
```

But I want the values to be in an order of item_names, (asset_min,hpc_max,off_median)

How can I do it using pyspark?

would much appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using databricks on any cloud platform?

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
w=Window.partitionBy("timestamp").orderBy("item_name").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.select(F.collect_list("item_value").over(w).alias("item_values"), F.col("timestamp"))\
.groupBy("timestamp")\
.agg(F.first("item_values").alias("item_values"))\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

```
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|item_name |item_value|timestamp                   |
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|hpc_max   |0.25      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.3       |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|hpc_max   |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.32      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.67      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|hpc_max   |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.32      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.67      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+------------------+
|timestamp                   |item_values       |
+----------------------------+------------------+
|2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|[0.34, 0.25, 0.67]|
|2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|[0.54, 0.54, 0.3] |
|2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|[0.32, 0.32, 0.67]|
+----------------------------+------------------+
```