# how to convert values in a column to array in an order defined in a list

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a list of values like below

```
[hpc_max,asset_min,off_median]
```

and a table like this

```
| item_name | item_value | timestamp                     |
| --------- | ----------| -----------------------------|
| hpc_max   | 0.25      | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.34      | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| off_median| 0.30      | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| hpc_max   | 0.54      | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.32      | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
| off_median| 0.67      | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.54      | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| off_median| 0.32      | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
| hpc_max   | 0.67      | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
```

and I want to group the item_values based on the timestamp in an array type in the order of item names that are in the list

The output I want is

| item_name | item_value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["hpc_max","asset_min","off_median"] | [0.25,0.34,0.67] | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| ["hpc_max","asset_min","off_median"] | [0.54,0.54,0.30] | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| ["hpc_max","asset_min","off_median"] | [0.67,0.32,0.32] | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |

how can I do this using pyspark?

would appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you've already posted this question earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793703/how-do-i-group-by-timestamp-in-an-order-of-values-in-a-column/75800091#75800091 ? I've responded with an answer as well

Comment: but it has to be in an order in a list... could you please answer the question again here?

Comment: Got it, I'll add an answer. Also, if the last one helped can you please accept and upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame (df_1)

```
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|item_name |item_value|timestamp                   |
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|hpc_max   |0.25      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.3       |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|hpc_max   |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.32      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.67      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.32      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
|hpc_max   |0.67      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Try this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, collect_list

df_2 = df_1.withColumn("item_index",
                       when(col("item_name")=="hpc_max", 1) \
                       .when(col("item_name")=="asset_min", 2) \
                       .otherwise(3)
                      )

df_3 = df_2.orderBy("timestamp","item_index")

df_3.groupBy("timestamp").agg(
    collect_list("item_name").alias("item_name"),
    collect_list("item_value").alias("item_value")
).show(truncate=False)
```

***Output***

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|timestamp                   |item_name                       |item_value        |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|[hpc_max, asset_min, off_median]|[0.67, 0.32, 0.32]|
|2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|[hpc_max, asset_min, off_median]|[0.54, 0.54, 0.3] |
|2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|[hpc_max, asset_min, off_median]|[0.25, 0.34, 0.67]|
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: this is not in the right order. it has to be in a order specified in the list. [hpc_max,asset_min,off_median]

Comment: Updated my solution accordingly.